# Converting from Sweref99tm to WGS84

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84

I have a lot of coordinates I want to convert from Sweref99tm to WGS84 for display on google maps. I'm using gdal installed on my laptop:

```
$ echo "6782384 599140" | gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:3006 -t_srs EPSG:4326
64.1363442998149 3.53655177487795 0
```

But according to [several](http://www.lantmateriet.se/en/Self-service/Enkel-koordinattransformation/) [sites](https://rl.se/rt90) online where I input the same coordinates, I get `61.163396, 16.842654` returned instead.

Anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Give coordinates in order easting- northing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gdaltrasform takes coordinates in longitude-latitude or easting-northing order. That is how GDAL always handles coordinates internally and perhaps that is so self-evident for GDAL developers that it is not documented in http://www.gdal.org/gdaltransform.html. All  you need to do is to flip the order of the coordinates

```
gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:3006 -t_srs EPSG:4326
599140 6782384
16.8426538013697 61.1633955987023 0
```